# Parallel Machine Scheduling by Lingo

Tags: scheduling, lindo

I try to solve Parallel Machine Scheduling Problem by LINGO, But the error code 63 "Model is ill define" was showed. Could you please advise me how to fix this error on my code as below;

Thank you in advance!!

```
    !Pararell MC scheduling model;
MODEL:
sets:
job/1..10/:;
mc/1..5/:;!k;
link(job):r,p,c;!i,j;
link1(job,mc):y,x;!ik;
link2(job,job,mc):N;!ijk;
endsets

data:
p=1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3;
r=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
G=10000;
enddata

min=Cmax;

@FOR(job(i):@SUM(mc(k):y(i,k))= 1);

@FOR(job(i):
    @FOR(job(j)|i#NE#j:
        @FOR(mc(k):x(i,k)+p(i)<=x(j,k)+(G*(1-N(i,j,k))))));
@FOR(job(i):
    @FOR(job(j)|i#NE#j:
        @FOR(mc(k):x(j,k)+p(j)<=x(i,k)+(G*N(i,j,k)))));

@FOR(link1:x(i,k)>=r(i));
@FOR(link1:x(i,k)>=0);

@FOR(link1:x(i,k)+p(i)=c(i));
Cmax=@max(link:c(i));

@For(link1:@bin(y));
@For(link2:@bin(N));

end
```